# Check if item field exist in pymongo database using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pymongo

I'm trying to check if `item ['email']` already exists in database, if it does not exist then insert into pymongo database.

i do not want duplicate emails within the pymongo database.

however i get this

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 17; 2 is
>   required

this is what i have so far

**Pipelines.py**

```
class myExporter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        i = 0
        while os.path.exists(SRCFILE % i):
            i += 1
        self.filename = SRCFILE % i
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as output:
            output = csv.writer(output)
            output.writerow(['Email', 'Website', 'Phone Number', 'Location'])
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(settings['MONGODB_HOST'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DATABASE']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.email = self.collection.find(dict(item['email']))
        for x in self.email:
            if x not in self.email:               
                self.collection.insert(dict(item))
                log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
                    settings['MONGODB_DATABASE'],
                    settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
                    settings['MONGODB_HOST'],
                    settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
                with open(self.filename, 'a') as output:
                    output = csv.writer(output)
                    output.writerow([item['email'],
                                     item['website'],
                                     item['phonenumber'],
                                     item['location']])
                folder = os.path.join(DESTINATION_FOLDER, os.path.basename(self.filename))
                shutil.copy(self.filename, folder)
                return item

class MongoPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'scrapy_items'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(dict(item))
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is when calling `self.collection.find(dict(item['email']))`.
`item` is already a dictionary which contains the key `email`, so there's 
no need to wrap it with `dict()`. Using `item['email']` will access the value of email just fine.

You should then check if `self.email` and see if it contains the required result, and proceed with the rest of the function logic.

**EDIT**

The new error from your comment indicates the filter in the lookup query needs to be, among other things, a dictionary. Use `{'email': item['email']}` if you are looking for an `email` field in Mongo.

Comment: let me give this a try

Comment: it gives me `TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping`

Comment: i just tried that before you did the edit and no errors but i still see duplicate emails in my database.

Comment: @JimmySmith For that you can create a unique index for the `email` field. Use `collection..create_index('email', unique=True)`. Now an error will be thrown whenever you try to add a document with an email that already exists in the collection.

Comment: let me give this a shot

Comment: its throwing the error, however its only showing one duplicate consistently. 

`raise DuplicateKeyError(errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myitems.scrapy_items index: email_1 dup key: { : "myemail...`

over and over, and i know there is more duplicates

Comment: Isn't that desired behavior ?

Comment: sort of, i just want no duplicate emails in the database, i know there is more duplicates than that reoccuring email

Comment: for example if email not in database, insert into database

Comment: Well that's not too hard. That part you'll have to do for yourself.. put a little work in and you will figure it out. Try catching the error (this means there's a duplicate) or doing something if an error wasn't thrown....

Answer (score 0):

`dropDups = True` will not save emails that has been already added to the database

`self.collection.ensure_index('email', unique=True, dropDups=True)`

finished code

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.email = self.collection.find({"email": item['email']})
    self.collection.ensure_index('email', unique=True, dropDups=True)
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
    log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
        settings['MONGODB_DATABASE'],
        settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
        settings['MONGODB_HOST'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
    with open(self.filename, 'a') as output:
        output = csv.writer(output)
        output.writerow([item['email'],
                         item['website'],
                         item['phonenumber'],
                         item['location']])
    folder = os.path.join(DESTINATION_FOLDER, os.path.basename(self.filename))
    shutil.copy(self.filename, folder)
    return item
```